# What does keras normalize axis argument does?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mnist

I am a beginner in deep learning and I am working upon the mnist dataset in keras.

I used normalization as

```
tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis = 1)
```

I don't understand what does the axis argument means. Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normalize function just performs a regular normalization to improve performance:

> Normalization is a rescaling of the data from the original range so
> that all values are within the range of 0 and 1.

There is a nice explanation of the axis argument in another post:

> [What is the meaning of axis=-1 in keras.argmax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435526/what-is-the-meaning-of-axis-1-in-keras-argmax)

For example:

> Your data has some shape (19,19,5,80). This means:
>
> - Axis = 0 - 19 elements
> - Axis = 1 - 19 elements
> - Axis = 2 - 5 elements
> - Axis = 3 - 80 elements

Also, for those who want to go deeper, there is an explanation from François Chollet - Keras’ author- on GitHub:

> - For Dense layer, all RNN layers and most other types of layers, the
>   default of axis=-1 is what you should use,
> - For Convolution2D layers
>   with dim_ordering=“th” (the default), use axis=1,
> - For Convolution2D
>   layers with dim_ordering=“tf”, use axis=-1 (i.e. the default).
>
> https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1921

Comment: Quick follow up to this, I'm trying to do deep learning on spectrograms with two channels. I have a tensor with shape (50, 50, 60, 2). I want to normalize every spectrogram and each channel (so along the (:, 50, 60, :) axis. When I do normalize(tens[: , :, :, 0], axis=0)[0][0] == normalize(tens[0, :, :, 0])[0] I get all False. Why is that? Shouldn't they be the same?

Answer (score 3):

`keras.utils.normalize()` function [calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571871/2099607) the [`numpy.linalg.norm()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) to compute the norm and then normalize the input data. The given `axis` argument is therefore passed to `norm()` function to compute the norm along the given axis.