# What does the `order` argument mean in `tf.keras.utils.normalize()`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, normalization

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[.8, .6], [.1, 0]])
B1 = tf.keras.utils.normalize(A, axis=0, order=1)
B2 = tf.keras.utils.normalize(A, axis=0, order=2)

print('A:')
print(A)
print('B1:')
print(B1)
print('B2:')
print(B2)
```

which returns

```
A:
[[0.8 0.6]
 [0.1 0. ]]
B1:
[[0.88888889 1.        ]
 [0.11111111 0.        ]]
B2:
[[0.99227788 1.        ]
 [0.12403473 0.        ]]
```

I understand how `B1` is computed via `order=1` such that each entry in `A` is divided by the sum of the elements in its column. For example, `0.8` becomes `0.8/(0.8+0.1) = 0.888`. However, I just can't figure out how `order=2` produces `B2` nor can I find any documentation about it.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571752/what-is-the-purpose-of-keras-utils-normalize/52571871#52571871) it calls numpy [linalg.norm()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) under the hood, you can see the "notes" section of that page for a description of the `order` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I just can't figure out how order=2 produces B2 nor can I find any documentation about it.

`order=1` means L1 norm while `order=2` means L2 norm. For L2 norm, You need to take the square root after summing the individual squares. Which elements to square depends on the axis.

**Keras**

```
A = np.array([[.8, .6], [.1, 0]])
B2 = tf.keras.utils.normalize(A, axis=0, order=2)
print(B2)

array([[0.99227788, 1.        ],
       [0.12403473, 0.        ]])
```

**Manual**

```
B2_manual = np.zeros((2,2))
B2_manual[0][0] = 0.8/np.sqrt(0.8 ** 2 + 0.1 ** 2)
B2_manual[1][0] = 0.1/np.sqrt(0.8 ** 2 + 0.1 ** 2)
B2_manual[0][1] = 0.6/np.sqrt(0.6 ** 2 + 0 ** 2)
B2_manual[1][1] =  0 /np.sqrt(0.6 ** 2 + 0 ** 2)
print(B2_manual)

array([[0.99227788, 1.        ],
       [0.12403473, 0.        ]])
```

You can look up the different types of Norm here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)
Worked examples:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

Answer (score 0):

Order 1 normalize the input such that the sum of the absolute value of all element is 1 (L1 norm of the input equals 1). Order 2 normalize the input such that the sum of the squared value of all element is 1 (L2 norm of the input equals 1).

Answer (score 0):

Passing order 2 in the `order` parameter, means you will be applying **Tikhonov regularization** commonly known as **L2** or **Ridge**. L1 and L2 are different regularization techniques, both with pros and cons you can read in detail here in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) and here in [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/l1-norms-versus-l2-norms). The approach for L2 is to solve the standard equation for regresison, when calculating residual sum of squares adding an extra term **λβTβ** which is the square of the transposed matrix Beta (that's why it is called L2, because of the sqaure).