# Axis parameter in the keras normalization function- keras.utils.normalization()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science, normalization

I spent a lot of time trying to understand how the axis argument works in the keras.utils.normalization() function. Can someone please explain it to me by using the concept of np.array by making a random (2,2) np array and explain how the normalization actually works for different axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a `2*2` `Numpy Array`,

```
x = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,4]])
```

`Axis = 0` indicates that the Operation is done **`Row-wise`**. Code with `Axis = 0`:

```
x_norm_rows_axis = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x, axis= 0)
print(x_norm_rows_axis)
```

Output of the above code is:

```
[[0.31622777 0.4472136 ]
 [0.9486833  0.89442719]]
```

The output of `Axis = 0` can be elaborated as shown below:

```
print('x_norm_rows_axis[0][0] = {}'.format(1/np.sqrt(1 ** 2 + 3 ** 2)))
print('x_norm_rows_axis[0][1] = {}'.format(2/np.sqrt(2 ** 2 + 4 ** 2)))
print('x_norm_rows_axis[1][0] = {}'.format(3/np.sqrt(1 ** 2 + 3 ** 2)))
print('x_norm_rows_axis[1][1] = {}'.format(4/np.sqrt(2 ** 2 + 4 ** 2)))
```

Output of the above `Print` Statements is shown below:

```
x_norm_rows_axis[0][0] = 0.31622776601683794
x_norm_rows_axis[0][1] = 0.4472135954999579
x_norm_rows_axis[1][0] = 0.9486832980505138
x_norm_rows_axis[1][1] = 0.8944271909999159
```

`Axis = 1` indicates that the Operation is done **`Column-wise`**. Code with `axis = 1`. In this case, since we have only 2 Dimensions, we can consider this as `axis = -1` as well:

```
x_norm_col_axis = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x, axis= 1)
print(x_norm_col_axis)
```

Output of the above code is:

```
[[0.4472136  0.89442719]
 [0.6        0.8       ]]
```

The output of `axis = 1` or `axis = -1` (in this case)  can be elaborated as shown below:

```
print('x_norm_col_axis[0][0] = {}'.format(1/np.sqrt(1 ** 2 + 2 ** 2)))
print('x_norm_col_axis[0][1] = {}'.format(2/np.sqrt(2 ** 2 + 1 ** 2)))
print('x_norm_col_axis[1][0] = {}'.format(3/np.sqrt(4 ** 2 + 3 ** 2)))
print('x_norm_col_axis[1][1] = {}'.format(4/np.sqrt(3 ** 2 + 4 ** 2)))
```

Output of the above `Print` Statements is shown below:

```
x_norm_col_axis[0][0] = 0.4472135954999579
x_norm_col_axis[0][1] = 0.8944271909999159
x_norm_col_axis[1][0] = 0.6
x_norm_col_axis[1][1] = 0.8
```

To understand how the `Order` argument works, refer this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58178948/13465258).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: Thank you so much ! That was a perfect explanation . Thanks again :D