# Tensorflow normalize Vs. traditional way of subtracting mean and dividing by std

Tags: python, tensorflow, normalization

I'm curious about any preference of using `tf.keras.utils.normalize` vs the way we usually normalize a series, subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

series = np.random.random(10) + 10 * np.sin(np.random.random(1))
mean = np.mean(series)
std = np.std(series)

(series - mean) / std

tf.keras.utils.normalize(series)
```

Is there any pros/cons for either method?

tf normalize in [0,1] range, but we get values in [-1,1] range using the other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.keras.utils.normalize` uses the algorithm described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571752/what-is-the-purpose-of-keras-utils-normalize), so it just makes the data along the specified axis a unit vector with respect to your favorite `lp` norm. Whether this is preferable to `sklearn.StandardScaler()` depends on the problem. For many time series problems, you want to detrend them, so make the mean `0.`, so `StandardScaler` is appropriate. If you want the inputs reasonably similarly scaled, both methods are equivalent, more or less.